# Check whether an element is visible on the screen

Tags: javascript, html

In a complex web application, I have to check whether certain HTML elements are visible partly/completely on the screen.

There are various reasons why certain elements are not visible on the screen:

- They have certain attributes, like display:none visibility:hidden width:0 height:0 opacity:0 and maybe others.
- Other elements are in front of the element.
- They are outside the parent's visible scroll area.
- To a certain extent, some of their parents have one or more of the properties above (elements with absolute or fixed positioning break the chain).
- They are outside the parent's visible area for other reasons, for instance the parent may be partly overlaid by other elements and they are only covering that part.

The things I found on stack overflow (like [How to Check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport and others) are doing simple checks for one or two of the reasons above, but do not even nearly try to detect *all* reasons I lined out.

Before I now start implementing everything manually, including all the corner cases: Is there a reason-agnostic check available through javascript, that will give me feedback on whether the element is visible in the rendered result?

For now, the easiest and most reliable thing I could come up with was the idea (didn't test it yet) to modify the background-color attribute of the element, use the html2canvas library before and after, and check whether the resulting images match.

Is there anything short of that "workaround"?

(Update: I have tested my html2canvas approach and not only is it slow, it also gives false positives because the images are not always the same, even if the element with changed background-color is not visible at all.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: @PhilippSander, that only covers one reason that might hide an element. this is not a duplicate.

Comment: upvoting again as i think this is a legitimate question, although i doubt there is a viable solution to this, as javascript doesn't have such detailed access to the rendering engine

Comment: And now comes the "Why do you need to know that?" question. Because, the answer is nope, nothing short, even the browser doesn't know when it does its painting (except obvious cases you already found). Compositing is done in a way that bottom layers must be drawn even if at the end they'll not be visible.

Comment: @Kaiido I need to know which elements are visible on screenshots I am about to take, because I want to provide the screenshots of an existing, extensive, untranslated app to translators so they can see the context of the strings they translate. Makes no sense to show them screenshots in which they cannot find the string, just because the string is in the DOM, but not visible on the screenshot, and the expected number of screenshots makes a programmatic solution more viable than manual sorting.